# Ways to print a specific number of items from a Dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm working on a school assignment that provides us with a couple of different `CSV` files. What I've done is give the user the ability to choose the number of items from the `dict` that will be printed out.

I've read the different dicts into lists:
`neg = [l for l in neg_Pool]`
`pos = [l for l in p_Pool]`
`neu = [l for l in neu_Pool]`

Now I'm trying to have just a certain number of the items from the lists printed as given by `num_items`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried progressing through a `for` loop:
`for i in range(pos(0, num_items-1)):`
`print(pos[i])`

However, I keep getting the same error message:
`TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

I tried calling the first element of the list with `print(pos[0])` and it works just fine, but it's the moment that I try and call multiple with the `for` loop that it gives me that.

Any suggestions on what I need to do or what my issue might be? If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: Why `range(pos(0, ...`, rather than just `range(0, ...` - what were you thinking the list would do there?

Comment: Can you plz, share your code here?

Comment: I cannot believe the idea of taking out the pos in the for loop didn't occur to me. I'm very tired right now so that's all I can think of. That worked. Thanks. Not I just need to figure out how to get it to print a certain way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with the following

1. Assuming `0 <= num_items <= len(neg)`:

   ```
   for i in range(num_items):
       print(neg[i])
   ```
2. Assuming `0 <= num_items <= len(pos)`:

   ```
   for i in range(num_items):
       print(pos[i])
   ```
3. Assuming `0 <= num_items <= len(neu)`:

   ```
   for i in range(num_items):
       print(neu[i])
   ```